# Be careful : French guy ahead

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, xubuntu, windows

https://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewforum.php?id=25

Be careful : French guy ahead.

```
Hi everybody,
```

I do have a hand made (not by me) anonymous PC.
It is a dual-boot machine; the guy who made it formatted 100 Go for W$10 and 150 Go for Xubuntu 22.04.
The problem is that I have no access to the internet from the linux side of that computer.
I have been almost thrown out of the French-speaking ubuntu (french-writing) forum because whilst tryibng to separate my problem into several easy and independant tasks,
these ones end to be rather numerous ( .../...
-"les sites ne s'ouvrent pas", which was the last prefeding topic when I just realized the roblem,
-"installation compliquée", which is the main topic,
-"transfert entre W10 et linux en dual-boot" which is a need when you cannot download from the linux side of a dual boot,
-"Installation avec Wget et dpkg" which is a need when the usual download and install of packets do noot work.
) and almost all the sections of the forum were (inondées) under the flood of my problem.
So please, try to answer one or more of my questions, or give me hints where I could seaerch for a solution.
David

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why the internet connection is not working on dual boot computers is that **Fast Startup** is not disabled on *Windows*. This means that *Windows* is not actually shutting down when you issue a **Shutdown**. The computer remains in a standby state and it doesn't release the network adapter so that it can be used by *Xubuntu*.

Please disable it on *Windows* and check if internet access is working on *Xubuntu* afterwards.

The link below will help you on how to do it.

https://www.howtogeek.com/856514/how-to-disable-fast-startup-on-windows-10/