# Wifi is not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, 22.04, windows

I have have installed ubuntu 22.04 along with windows 10 in my laptop. In windows wifi is working but in ubuntu wifi is not working.In the settings  the wifi option is not even visible. I tried various solution given on internet but none of them worked for me. So help me with this.

Comment: `inxi -N` is a  terminal command that can be executed, copied and pasted into your question. (No screenshots necessary). Add the output of the command into your question - so we can see if a driver is missing.

Comment: I have already answered this question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1469786/be-careful-french-guy-ahead

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)